# Centering column headers with SDK 2.0 RC2

Tags: rally, appsdk2

In previous versions of the SDK, specifying `align : 'center'` to a `rallygrid` column config would result in both the column contents and column header being horizontally centered. If I specify this setting now, the content is centered but not the header. With relatively wide columns this becomes an issue since the column header is no longer lining up with the column contents. Is there a separate setting for header alignment, or does this need to be accomplished using CSS?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in 2.0rc2 introduced by the restyling of the grid headers.  We never have centered headers in the product, so we styled them for the default left alignment and accidentally broke the center alignment.

You can fix this in your app by adding the following css override in your app css:

```
.yes-harmonized .rally-grid.x-grid .x-grid-header-ct .x-box-inner .x-column-header .x-column-header-inner { 
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Great.  We'll try to get this cleaned up for the next release so the workaround is no longer necessary.